# how to write python code to capture voice in android device

Tags: python, android, pyaudio

I wrote some code to capture voice from mic using `pyaudio` and `speech_recognition`. When I tried to execute it in my smartphone, it said `pyaudio` not supported.

The code I wrote listens and records the mic until silence period of 0.5 seconds.

But I believe, in practice running python in android box is easier then running it in laptop. That's why I need to run my code in a small and cheap box such as an android box.

I tried:

```
import pyaudio
from multiprocessing import Queue
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
import time
from googletrans import Translator 
import speech_recognition as sr 

......

with sr.Microphone() as source:       
    r.pause_threshold = 0.5
    audio = r.listen(source)
    queue.put(audio)
```

Comment: What do you mean executing python code in android device? Mention actually what are you trying to do. Are you running python code in android device using Command-line tools or any Interpreter or you have a module in python with wrapper code in java/kotlin or using pure python with kivy? Give detail explanation so we could help you further.

Comment: i plan to install pydroid in one android box then to run my code on it. i will connect a usb mic to this android box , apply my code to the captured voice and display the output on TV connected to HDMI interface of my android box